# Url missing apostrophe

Tags: php, javascript

I have 2 URL links. One works and the other one - which is called via PHP - does not. the PHP link is missing an apostrophe `'`. How can I fix this?

```
<?php print "[ <a href='javascript:change_url($urls)'>test2</a>";  ?>

<a href="javascript:change_url('test2.html')">test2</a>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content").load("test.html");
});

function change_url(file){
    $("#content").load(file);
}
</script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: `print "<a href=\"javascript:change_url('".htmlspecialchars(str_replace("'", "\\'", $urls))."');\">test2</a>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<?php print "[ <a href='javascript:change_url(" . str_replace( "'", "\'", $urls ) .")'>test2</a>";  ?>
```

Comment: it should be (<a href=\"javascript:change_url('".htmlspecialchars(str_replace("'", "\\'", $urls))."');\">test2</a>)... thanks for the input.

Comment: @DaveRandom Since your answer was the better one (and helped the OP)  I think it will be correct if you post it and the OP accepts it instead of mine. I'll upvote it too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `print`, run `htmlspecialchars` over `$urls` like so: `$urls = htmlspecicalchars($urls);`